# setSelected in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have a project where I need to change the selection of a tree widget in code. This needs to be done after I clear out the tree and populate it again.

I'm trying to mark the appropriate item as "selected" while I'm adding them. This works for root level nodes. But for child nodes, it doesn't. I need to store the QTreeWidgetItem in another variable and mark it as selected after the tree has been completely populated. Why does this happen?

This does not work:

```
def refreshTree(self):
    treeObj.clear()
    for item in items:
        temp = QTreeWidgetItem(0)
        for key, val in item.subitems().items():
            childTemp = QTreeWidgetItem(0)
            ...setup text, font, etc...

            if(condition1):
                childTemp.setSelected(True)
            temp.addChild(childTemp)

        if(!condition1 and condition2):
            temp.setSelected(True)

        treeObj.addToplevelItem(temp)
```

This does:

```
def refreshTree(self):
    treeObj.clear()
    for item in items:
        temp = QTreeWidgetItem(0)
        for key, val in item.subitems().items():
            childTemp = QTreeWidgetItem(0)
            ...setup text, font, etc...

            if(condition1):
                selTemp = childTemp
            temp.addChild(childTemp)

        if(!condition1 and condition2):
            temp.setSelected(True)
        elif(selTemp):
            selTemp.setSelected(True)
        treeObj.addToplevelItem(temp)
```

Comment: Can you show us some example code?

Comment: Could you show where the calls to `temp.addChild` (and `treeObj.addTopLevelItems`) are relative to the calls to `setSelected` ?

Comment: ^ Just added them to the code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not specified in the documentation, but `setSelected` does nothing if the item hasn't been added to a view yet:

```
inline void QTreeWidgetItem::setSelected(bool aselect)
{ if (view) view->setItemSelected(this, aselect); }
```

So, you should either

- pass `treeObj` or `temp` in the constructor of your `QTreeWidgetItem` to make them part of the view from the start
- or call `addChild`/`addTopLevelItem` before calling `setSelected` (or other functions like  `setExpanded`...).

I don't know why your second code was even working.